# Which machine does the Reducer of the Hadoop run on

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

If I have a 4 node cluster, where 1 machine is the namenode and the remaining 3 machines are datanodes, and if I set the number of reducers to 1, which of the data nodes will run the reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namenode and datanode are HDFS processes not MapReduce. I assume you have 3 task tracker nodes. One of them will run it. There is no guarantee which one. Hadoop generally moves computation to be near the data that it needs but for reducers they are pulling data from mappers not HDFS. You can say Hadoop will prefer a less loaded node with at least one reduce slot.